# Printing category prints array?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm trying to print the category with this code and it keeps printing array?

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=1&orderby=desc'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br /><?php print(get_the_category($id)); ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post may be in more than one category hence an array is returned further it is an array of objects.
Here is an example from the documentation.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```